# What crimes get one sent to azkaban

Tags: harry-potter

What crimes are punished with sentences in Azkaban? Or what must be proved in a trial to merit a stay in Azkaban other than murder?

Answer (score 2):

It is really the Wizengamot who decides whether a crime was heinous enough to merit time in Azkaban. So, truly, *any* crime could result in Azkaban if the court deems it to be.

However, here are just a couple moments from the series which may help.

## Unforgivable Curses

> Moody: Earn you a one-way ticket to Azkaban.
>
> <sub>From movie script of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*</sub>

## Breaking and Entering

> Podmore was arrested by Ministry of Magic watchwizard Eric Munch, who found him attempting to force his way through a top- security door at one o’clock in the morning. Podmore, who refused to speak in his own defence, was convicted on both charges and sentenced to six months in Azkaban.
>
> <sub>From *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* (book)</sub>

## Opening the Chamber of Secrets

> “For a short stretch only,” said Fudge, not meeting Hagrid’s eyes. “Not a punishment, Hagrid, more a precaution. If someone else is caught, you’ll be let out with a full apology —”
>
> “Not Azkaban?” croaked Hagrid.
>
> <sub>From *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* (book)</sub>

Comment: Ouch! Going to Azkaban for Breaking and Entering is a bit rough...

Comment: @Rebel-Scum Agreed, but that was at the time that they were trying to neutralize the Order.